# Get payload info from pdu with logica SMPP

Tags: smpp, pdu

How to get payload information from pdu with logica SMPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy:

```
DeliverSm dSm = (DeliverSM)pdu;
byte[] payLoad = deliverSM.getMessagePayload().getBuffer();
```